# Arbortext Editor Adapter Creation

Tags: javascript, java

I'm creating adapter for arbortext editor. Also i'm able to create the structured adapter, but while initializing the adapter i'm getting

> registerAdapter is not a function, it is org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaPackage.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the problem, by deleting the target folder and rebuild the classes, then created adapter jar. Now i'm able to register my adapter.